# Need to convert double or decimal to string

Tags: c#, .net, string

I need to convert double to string with two decimal digits separated with 'dot'
My concern is that dot must be always used as separator.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The simplest way is to specify `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as the culture, e.g.

```
string text = d.ToString("N2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Jon, does CultureInfo.InvariantCulture assume 'dot'?

Comment: @Captain Comic: Yes. For *most* purposes, you can think of the invariant culture as being pretty much US English :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps to avoid messing up with CultureInfo settings on clients systems, we better set a concrete way to force the machine to use dot as decimal separator and not thousand separator ==> regardless of culture! So,

```
NumberFormatInfo fi= new NumberFormatInfo();
fi.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
string doubleDotDecimalNr = doubleNr.ToString(fi);
```