# How to format double in C# to such format?

Tags: c#, format, double

I have problem with formatting double in C#. I want to achieve format like this:
2.0, but I get an exception.

```
string result = string.Format("{0.0}",  2.0d);
```

I get Format Exception, Input string was not in a correct format. When I change code to:

```
string result = string.Format("{0:0.0}",  2.0d);
```

I get comma, not drop as separator. Is there some way to get 2.0 from string.format without any other functions?

Comment: "I get comma, not drop as separator" -- I believe this is due to your culture settings.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076789/converting-double-to-string-with-n-decimals-dot-as-decimal-separator-and-no-th

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:0.0}",  2.0d);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a comma because of your system's locale. If you'd like to always get a `.`, specify culture invariance:

```
string result = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:N1}", 2.0d);
```

Have a look at [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead of using `String.Format()`:

```
var param = 2.0d
string result = param.ToString("N1");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, putting the culture that u prefer:

```
string result = string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB"),"{0:0.0}", 2.0d);
```