# C# - How to convert , in

Tags: c#, converters

How to convert in C# a double with 1,77 to 1.77?

I have a input text with 1,77 and I want to replace to 1.77.

I have tried

```
alturaaux =Convert.ToDouble(altura2).ToString(#,##);
```

but without success.

Comment: this question can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076789/converting-double-to-string-with-n-decimals-dot-as-decimal-separator-and-no-th

Comment: Why convert to double? Use the native String.replace method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czx8s9ts(v=vs.110).aspx. You don't have a *double* to begin with.

Comment: Why are you getting 1,77?  Is it a culture thing (i.e. many European cultures use `,` as the decimal separator).  If you are storing something that is really a decimal as a string, maybe you should look into converting it at storage time when you are in the correct culture.

Answer (score 2):

You can first get it to a string than replace the comma to a dot.

```
string entered = "1,77";
string doubleString = entered.Replace(',', '.');

if(Double.TryParse(doubleString, out number))
    return number;
else 
   return null;
```

Comment: +1 for the correct suggestion, though all this can be done in a single line.

Comment: He said he is going to have the user input their region currency, so I broke it down enough for him to understand, plus I believe he is cheating on homework so better make him look at more code than needed.

Answer (score 0):

use `TryParse` method like

```
double ret;
double.TryParse("1,77".Replace(",", "."), out ret);
```