# Convert string to double but missing a dot

Tags: c#

So im trying to convert the string to a double but everytime it converts the string its missing the dot.
This is for a currency calculataor.

My code:

```
 private void listBoxLeft_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var valuta = listBoxLeft.SelectedItem.ToString();
        var valutaCurrencySplit = valuta.Split(':');
        var currency = valutaCurrencySplit[1];
        currency = currency.Replace(" ", String.Empty);

        Problem starts here...

        double finalNumber = Convert.ToDouble(finalString);

        Console.WriteLine(finalNumber);
    }
```

finalNumber ends as 74361, but should be 7.4361

Comment: What value does `finalString` have?

Comment: Sorry, seems i deleted that line. It does have the same value as currency. Just tried to do ToString again to see if that fixed it

Comment: What is the value of finalString ?

Comment: the value is = 7.4361

Comment: This link might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076789/converting-double-to-string-with-n-decimals-dot-as-decimal-separator-and-no-th

Comment: I just tried and it works for me. Probably a CultureInfo issue.

Comment: Okay, i will try the link Arib Yousuf sent me to fix CultureInfo. Thanks to Both of u.

Comment: [Do not use floating point types for monetary amounts.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3730040/982149)

Comment: @Fildor Interesting, thanks for the notice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```cs
string finalString = "7.4361";
decimal finalNumber = decimal.Parse(finalString, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

// 7.4361
```

Answer (score 1):

**My Code:**

```
string str = "3.234";
double strf = Double.Parse(str, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
// output: 3.234
```