# Save double with dot format using StringBuilder

Tags: c#, double, stringbuilder

```cs
stringBuilder.Append(doubleVariable.ToString());
```

In my case it will write it as for example `0,15` and I would definitely prefer `0.15`.

I did not find any direct answer to that, I bet it can be applied somehow to `ToString()`.

Comment: This is culture thing, research that, also format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076789/converting-double-to-string-with-n-decimals-dot-as-decimal-separator-and-no-th) the issue is indeed born in `Double.ToString()`, however it is quite easy to apply formatting to get your period

> value.ToString("0.00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)